# CountIfs variable range

Tags: vba, excel

As written, I am not having problems with the code shown below.

However, I will not always have 5520 rows, so I am trying to replace `range("L2:L5520")` with `range(cells(2,12),cells(rng.Rows.Count,12))` where rng is predefined above as range and a watch on rng.Rows.Count confirms the present value is 5520.

```
For r = 7 To 11
    For c = 2 To 5
        Cells(r, c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("PA2_Data").range("L2:L5520"), Sheets("PA2_Tables").Cells(6, c), Sheets("PA2_Data").range("F2:F5520"), Sheets("PA2_Tables").Cells(r, 1))
    Cells(r, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("PA2_Tables").range(Cells(r, 2), Cells(r, 5)))
Next r
```

With `range(cells(2,12),cells(rng.Rows.Count,12))` I get an error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the code is trying to do.  I have a few suggestions though: 1)  Specify the worksheet instead of just using "range(....)", so "ws.range(.....)" where ws is set as the worksheet you are trying to use before this.  2)  Are you sure "rng" has been initialized to something?  3) Why not just define a name as something like "DataRange" and use this defined name in your formulas?  Then you can just update the DataRange each time....

Comment: An additional comment is that if you want to use the last row, then what you want to do is store the lastrow in a Long variable and then put this into your formula.  Do a search for finding the last used row in a worksheet (there are many good sources for this) to get this value.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I was able to change the range statement to `range(Sheets("PA2_Data").Cells(2, 12), Sheets("PA2_Data").Cells(lastrow, 12)` and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if rng was declared such that the statement you have will work, but what you likely want to do is use a "last row" variable instead of the rng one you are using.

So try this:

```
 Dim lastrow As long
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set ws = Sheets("PA2_Tables")
 lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.count, "A").end(xlUp).row

 ....

For r = 7 To 11
    For c = 2 To 5
        Cells(r, c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("PA2_Data").range("L2:L" & lastrow), Sheets("PA2_Tables").Cells(6, c), Sheets("PA2_Data").range("F2:F" & lastrow), Sheets("PA2_Tables").Cells(r, 1))
        Cells(r, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("PA2_Tables").range(Cells(r, 2), Cells(r, 5)))
    Next c
Next r

With range(cells(2,12),cells(lastrow,12)) 


......
```